# Laravel Belongs to many returning empty

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I'm having issues with returning belongs to many relationship. Here is my scenario. I have "**Individual**" model and "**Group**" model where each *individual can belongs to many groups* and each *group can belongs to many user*. Working with database blueprint such as "localhost/phpmyadmin" is fine as I can click at 'group' column on "group_individual" table and it returns to the related group on "groups" table. But working inside Laravel, I'm getting empty array. Can you help me please? Thank you for your time.

**Migrations**

```php
Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('group_id')->unique();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('members');
    $table->string('url')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('individuals', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('search_id')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('group_individual',function($table){
    $table->id();
    $table->string('group');
    $table->string('individual');
    $table->foreign('group')->references('group_id')->on('groups')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('type');
    $table->foreign('individual')->references('search_id')->on('individuals')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**Individual model**

```php
public function groups():\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class,'group_individual','individual','group');
}
```

**Group model**

```php
public function individuals():\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Individual::class,'group_individual','group','individual');
}
```

**Controller**

```php
public function import(){
    Individual::create([]);
    Group::create([]);
    \DB::table('group_individual')->insert(['group'=>,'individual'=>,'type'=>]);
    $individual=Individual::find(1);
    dd($individual->groups);
}
```

`$individual->groups` from above controller returns empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I tried to use id of both tables instead of custom other attributes.
Here is the code that I use. Instead of using **DB::insert()** method, I use **attach** method.

**Migrations**

```
Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('group_id')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('members');
            $table->string('url')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
     
    Schema::create('individuals', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('search_id')->unique();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
    Schema::create('group_individual',function($table){
               $table->foreignId('group_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
               $table->foreignId('individual_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
               $table->string('type');
            });
```

**Individual Model**

```
public function groups(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class,'group_individual','individual_id','group_id');
    }
```

**Group Model**

```
public function individuals(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Individual::class,'group_individual','group_id','individual_id');
    }
```

**Controller**

```
$a=Individual::create();
$b=Group::create();
$a->groups()->attach($b->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've inverted the ID keys, try switching the 'group' and 'individual' around in the belongsToMany method

Comment: I tried  inside Individual model like "return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class,'group_individual','group','individual'); " but still returning empty array.

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but is the group, the individual and the group_individual table populated with data that's usable for laravel?

Comment: Yes I have data that can be usable. They are all successfully imported but can't be accessed via code. I have tested many to many relationships with only id just like in Laravel documentation other than other attributes before.

Comment: I don't know if it might be because of either the keys are string type or key names. I'm playing around with these conditions. Let me know if you have any idea.